# pip won't run. throws errors instead

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7, pip

I am running into problems when ever I run `pip` with any arguments or flags.  I've tried doing `apt-get install --reinstall python-pip` but it does not help and am at a loss how to fix this

Version of Ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Version of Python

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Pip version

```
$ dpkg -l | grep pip
ii  python-pip     1.5.4-1     all     alternative Python package installer
```

Error, I get the exact same error no matter what arguments or flags I try.

```
$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in   load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

Comment: What maybe solves this too is `easy_install -U pip`...

Comment: easy_install -U pip from  ByteCommander suggestion worked for me.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo#answer-50187211) works for Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 15):

Seems to be a bug that it is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991)

It should work if you install a later version of `pip`.

You can remove the current `pip` installation with:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

Then install it from github(it is a later version):

```
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

**Edit**

If it still won't work try this as it says so in the installation documentation(after you installed the new version):

To enable the use of `pip` from the command line, ensure the Scripts subdirectory of your Python installation is available on the system PATH. (This is not done automatically.)

**References:**

1. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991

Comment: This shouldn't be closed!!! Instead of wgetting that raw github file, follow https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html. In a nutshell say 1. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`, then 2. `sudo python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 3):

This problem is caused by a mismatch between your pip installation and your requests installation. First remove the python-pip package and then install the latest version of pip. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
sudo apt install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install -U pip
```

To update pip for Python 3.x replace `python-pip` with `python3-pip`, replace `python-setuptools` with `python3-setuptools`, and replace `easy_install` with `easy_install3`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the get-pip.py script from github is outdated, and the latest version is on pypa as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Installation is working but after it pip cannot be found. When I type pip in command line I get `bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `sudo python get-pip.py`, it may help.(I'm a macOS user now, sorry for no testing env)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and same Ubuntu versions.
easy_install was not working either.  Doing apt-get --reinstall had not worked.

You might try recompiling:

```
sudo python

>>>import compileall

>>>compileall.compile_dir('/usr/lib/python2.7', force=True)
```

now "pip list" works (I had previously removed all the pyc files but I don't think it is necessary or safe)

Answer (score 1):

Create a Symbolic link to /user/bin

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling python-pip from this website worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
```