# Cannot install and upgrade python packages on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install some python packages but I am getting this kind of error every time.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
"Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

I looked it up on this site and Stack Overflow and all the solutions suggest installing

```
wheel
```

or

```
setuptools
```

But I am getting

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

The same problem occurs for trying to upgrade python packages. What should I do?

Comment: 1. What commands you were using to install these Python packages? 2. Can you do `pip --version` and tell us what version of pip you are using?

Comment: One of the many commands I used that gave me error was:  pip install -U textblob and the pip version is: pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: @edwinksl Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install and update python packages using **sudo**
As an example:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pandas
```

or

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pandas
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 gnome and it works fine and it also worked fine before I upgraded, means on ubuntu 14.04. Maybe you can also try to upgrade pip itself using

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using sudo. But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Have also a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/561377/pip-wont-run-throws-errors-instead). The lowes answer, where you use wget to install an alternative pip might be the right answer.